# Create archetype catalog in Nexus

Tags: java, maven, nexus, maven-archetype

I have created a number of custom archetypes in my local repository. I know that I can create a catalog file by using `archetype:crawl`.

Now I want to put these archetypes into Nexus (easy enough) and create a named catalog in Nexus that I can point our developers to. How can the latter be done?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A reindex in Nexus will create the desired catalog. The name is just the name of the repository where the archetypes lie.